# What is the setsockopt option name of TCP_USER_TIMEOUT on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, tcp, setsockopt

I'm trying to port some code over to OSX - it appears that `setsockopt` has a few differences from Linux.  The one I've found and corrected so far is using TCP_KEEPALIVE instead of TCP_KEEPIDLE.

What is the equivalent to TCP_USER_TIMEOUT for OSX?

Using TCP_USER_TIMEOUT fails to compile and prints an `undeclared identifier` error

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compiler errors are printed on the console. They are not exceptions and they are not thrown.

Comment: Feel free to just edit the post with an explanation next time.

Comment: That would tell you, if you looked, but it wouldn't tell anyone else. It's a common mis-statement here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a macro named "TCP_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT" in tcp.h. I use it to replace TCP_USER_TIMEOUT  on Mac. It works well. You may try it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is `TCP_RXT_CONNDROPTIME` from the same header:

```
#define TCP_RXT_CONNDROPTIME    0x80    /* time after which tcp retransmissions will be 
                                         * stopped and the connection will be dropped
                                         */
```

I've found this weird [commit](http://52.8.102.37/docker/swarm/commit/15c9dbaee09876eb54267c5b6a83e9ff0ace2e5a) where there are three implementations provided for `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT`:

- Linux: `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` is set manually (seems like this code is quite outdated);
- Darwin: `TCP_RXT_CONNDROPTIME` is used;
- Win: no implementation provided.

This commit might be a clue, but I haven't tested it myself. I just hope that this information could be helpful to someone.

Check `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` and `TCP_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT` descriptions in the [Linux man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) and [BSD man](https://www.manpagez.com/man/4/tcp/) - they doesn't seem to be very similar.